# DirectX 11 Video Playback

Tags: windows, c++11, directx-11, video-player

I'm looking to implement a video player within a game engine, effectively decoding a video file and rendering the result to a texture in DirectX 11.  Unfortunately I'm a bit clueless on how to do this but I've found the ID3D11VideoDevice class on MSDN but have no idea how to use it and I can't seem to find any useful samples/examples online that show how it's used.

I've started by trying to query the interface oh my created ID3D11Device with the following code:

```
ComPtr<ID3D11VideoDevice> video;
HRESULT hr = device->QueryInterface(__uuidof(ID3D11VideoDevice), &video);
```

But I get the HRESULT E_NOINTERFACE, so I'm guessing I've created the original device in such a way that I can't convert it to a video device?  Either that or this is completely the wrong way to go about it.  So my questions would be:

1. Is how I'm starting correct and if so why do I get this error?
2. Does anybody know of any useful documentation/samples online that can explain how this is done?

Just for reference below is how I'm creating the original ID3D11Device:

```
std::vector<D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL> feature_levels = {
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_1,
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0,
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_1,
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_0,
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_3,
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_2,
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_1
};

UINT flags = 0;
#if defined(DEBUG) || defined(_DEBUG)
    flags |= D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG;
#endif

// Create D3D device
HRESULT hr = D3D11CreateDevice(nullptr,
    D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE,
    0,
    flags,
    &feature_levels[0],
    feature_levels.size(),
    D3D11_SDK_VERSION,
    &m_device,
    &m_featureLevel,
    &m_deviceContext);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The Direct3D 11 Video interfaces are extremely low-level, so using them directly to play back media is not recommended. Instead you should look at using Media Foundation or a 3rd party video solution.

Comment: What version of Windows are you targeting here? Windows 10, Windows 8.x, Windows 7?

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn Sorry it's targeting Windows 7 using Visual Studio 2013, isn't Media Foundation just as low level? Using decoders, streams etc?  My understanding was WMF was the low level part and using DirectX to render the result to a texture was the higher level part?

Comment: Direct3D 11 Video is very low-level and is used by Media Foundation which is therefore a 'higher' level API.

Comment: Ok thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the comment mentioning that you are using Windows 7, that's the reason you don't have Direct3D 11 video support.

The DirectX 11.1 Runtime can be installed on Windows 7 Service Pack 1 via [KB2670838](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2670838), but it only provides the software features per [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/jj863687.aspx). Any feature that requires new hardware features requires new [WDDM v1.2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn653369.aspx) drivers which is only supported on Windows 8.0 or later.

See [DirectX 11.1 and Windows 7](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2012/11/13/directx-11-1-and-windows-7/) and [DirectX 11.1 and Windows 7 Update](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2013/02/26/directx-11-1-and-windows-7-update/).

Comment: So basically ID3D11VideoDevice support is only for Windows 8?  We're limited in what service packs etc. that can be installed on the target hardware see.

Comment: Windows 8.0, Windows 8.1, or Windows 10.

Comment: OK great, thanks for the clarification, so effectively my only option seems to be to use Windows Media Foundation to open a video stream and somehow decoding each frame in to a 2D texture?

Just wanted to clarify as this is the road I've gone down using an IMFSourceReader which seems to load the stream correctly but I'm just a bit stumped on the decoding to a 2D texture step and just want to make sure I'm going about this the right way and not wasting my time.

Comment: This [walkthrough](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj207074.aspx) should help. It has some Windows Runtime code in it, but mostly it's just using Media Foundation an Direct3D 11.